# duplicating values in json file

Tags: python, json

I would like to duplicate values in yaml file with range 0 to 100. How can I duplicate it?

Comment: I would read the JSON file with the help of the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module, write code that creates a new structure with the intended changes to the current data, and then write back this data to the JSON file. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re ,json
labels= []
finduuid = re.findall('images/(.*?).png' , open('old.json', 'r').read())
for x in finduuid:
    for i in range(0,101):
        labels.append({
            "image_path": f"images/{x}_{str(i).zfill(2)}.png",
            "label": "",
            "aug": True
        })
with open('labels.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(labels, f)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.